# Program to find sum in an infinite array within given ranges

Tags: arrays, c++14

**Problem Statement: Given on Hackrearth**

Given an array, `A` of N integers, and you have also defined the new array `B` as a concatenation of array `A` for an infinite number of times.
For example, if the given array `A` is `[1,2,3]` then, infinite array `B` is `[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,.......]`.

Now you are given Q queries, each query consists of two integers `L` and `R`. Your task is to find the sum of the subarray from index `L` to `R` (both inclusive) in the infinite array `B` for each query.

Note: As the value of this output is very large, print the answer as modulus 10^9+7;

**Solution:**

```
vector<int> sumInRanges(vector<int> &arr, int n, vector<vector<long long>> &qrr, int q) {
   
    int mod=1e9+7;

    vector<long long>sarr(n+1,0);    // to store the prefix sum
    
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        sarr[i]=(sarr[i-1]+arr[i-1])%mod;
    }
    
    vector<int>ans;               //to store the final answer         
    
    for(int i=0;i<q;i++)
    {
        long long l,r;
        l=qrr[i][0];
        r=qrr[i][1];
        
        long long grp=(r/n)%mod;
        long long res=(grp*sarr[n])%mod;
        res=(res+sarr[r%n])%mod;
        long long rsum=res;
        
        l-=1;
        grp=(l/n)%mod;
        res=(grp*sarr[n])%mod;
        res=(res+sarr[l%n])%mod;
        long long lsum=res;

        int sum=((rsum-lsum+mod)%mod);
        ------------------------------
        ans.push_back(sum);
    }

    return ans;
}
```

**My doubt:**
I have solved the above problem like this, what I did is I first found the prefix array sum and then find the `rsum` up to range R corresponding to infinite array B and `lsum` up to range L-1 corresponding to infinite array B and then find the final answer as `(rsum - lsum)%mod` but I got some test cases as WA but when I did like this `(rsum - lsum+mod)%mod` all tests cases passed, my doubt is that what is the significance of adding "mod" in the above-highlighted line in the solution.

Comment: Please, put the language label you are using (I suppose it's C++)

Comment: Negative operands to `%` nay not do what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>
int res(vector<int>&arr,int p,int q1)
{ long long int n=arr.size(),sum=0;
  int mod=1e9+7;
    for(int i=p-1 ; i<q1;i++)
    { 
        sum=sum+arr[i%n];
    }
 return sum%mod;
}

vector<int> sumInRanges(vector<int> &arr, int n, vector<vector<long long>> &queries, int q) {
    long long int sum=0;
    vector<int>fin;
   for(int i=0;i<q;i++)
   {
      long long int p=queries[i][0] , q1=queries[i][1];
       fin.push_back(res(arr,p,q1));
   }
    return fin;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).